# Navigation menus design

Tags: css

I want to design a navigation menu something like:

```
  <ul id="menu">
        <li><a>link1</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a>sublink1</a></li>
            <li><a>sublink1</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>link2</a></li>
        <li><a>link3</a></li>
        <li><a>link4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

From css point of view how is better to write your code:
hide dropdown list with `position:absolute;` `left:-999em;` and on hoover `top:0; left:0;`
or
 `display:none;` and `display:block;` on hoover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using display instead of positioning is more correct as it actually hides the element instead of just moving it outside the page.

Besides, this also saves you 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide it then why not to use `display:none;` and `display:block;`? Any reason why you considering moving them instead?